# How can I get the source name of data piped to a Python script?

Tags: python, shell

I'm using Apache Tika to pull PDF content from a URL, and passing the results of Tika's discovery to a Python script. I'm able to get the content fine, but I'd also like to be able to get the URL I'm parsing. For example, running:

```
java -jar /usr/local/tika-1.7/tika-app/target/tika-app-1.7.jar -J -t https://somewebsite.com/a_pdf_document.pdf | ./my_script.py
```

passes

```
[{"Content-Length":"1121070","Content-Type":"application/pdf","Creation-Date":"2014-11-13T12:39:52Z","Keywords": ... ]
```

to `my_script.py`. But, I'd also like to be able to access the location of the file that was piped, e.g. `https://somewebsite.com/a_pdf_document.pdf`.

Since I'm piping the data, `sys.argv` won't work. Anything I'm missing that can do this?

Comment: Nope. You'd need to store that somewhere in the environment or pass it to python as an argument separately from the piped data or send it in the piped data with a delimiter or something.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the response--I can add it as an arg if I have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the piped data doesn't have a name.

You have a couple choices.

1. You can either pass the filename as an argument to the python script.
2. You can store the filename in the environment.
3. You can pass the filename as part of the piped data (with a delimiter).